# Managing WebDriver sessions when Injecting PageObject implementations with Java Spring Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I need to inject different PageObject implementations depending on some property, but faced a problem with managing WebDriver sessions.
Pages Config:

```
@Configuration
public class PageImplConfig {

    @Value("${application.url}")
    private String url;


    @Bean
    public IProductDetailsPage pdp() {
        if(url.contains("www.somesite.com")) {
            return new ProductDetailsPageHG();
        } else {
            return new ProductDetailsPageDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

WD Config:

```
    @Bean
    @Scope("browserscope")
    @Documented
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public WebDriver chromeDriver(){
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

Autowire interface:

```
public class PdpSteps extends SpringBaseTestNGTest {

    @Autowired
    protected IProductDetailsPage pdp;
}
```

When using it inside Scenarion Outline (cucumber) - first example works as it should, but when pdp is used for second example - it crashes with `'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?'`
How should I manage sessions properly?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a problem by adding @ScenarioScope to PageImplConfig

```
@Bean
@ScenarioScope
public IProductDetailsPage pdp() {
    if(url.contains("www.hotelgiftcard.com")) {
        return new ProductDetailsPageHG();
    } else {
        return new ProductDetailsPage();
    }
}
```